# Searching for data in MYSQL and put it in a php if else statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making a sign up page and i'm trying to find out how you can make it say a warning note for someone who's going to register a username that's already been taken/in the database. Here's what I tried to do

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    echo "<span style='color:red'><strong>The following information are required:</strong><br />";

    if (empty($_POST["mx1"])) {
        echo "required username<br />";
    }

    /*my attempt at the warning note*/
    if (mysqli_query($trigerconn,"SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE Username=''$_POST[mx1]''")) {
        echo "Username is already taken<br />";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["mx2"])) {
        echo "required password<br />";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["mx3"])) {
        echo "required email address<br />";
    }   

    if ($_POST["mx4"] == "0" || empty($_POST["mx4"])) {
        echo "age number required";
    }

    echo "</span>";      
}
```

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d. And I suggest you read [the docs](http://php.net/mysqli_query) to see why your `if()` test will never work... that's NOT how you check for a field's existence.

Comment: i'm aware of stripslashes and htmlspecialchars thank you very much that's not the concern at hand... And like I said i'm new at this, that's like half an excuse but still

Comment: It's not even gonna be a real website i'm just trying to make a login form.

Answer (score 0):

You must use prepared statements to protect yourself from SQL injection attack:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM UserData WHERE Username=?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST[mx1]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if(isset($data['id']))
    {
        echo "Username is already taken<br />";
    }
}
```

I presume, that you have id column in your table. If you don't change 'id' to your primary key name for UserData table.

Answer (score -1):

Didn't test this yet, but try this.

```
$result = mysql_query(mysqli_query($trigerconn,"SELECT * FROM UserData WHERE Username=''$_POST[mx1]''"));
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {

echo "Username already taken";

}
else {
  //Your code here
}
```

Comment: mysql_* functions have been deprecated, the PO is using mysqli

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use mysqli the way you tried. To do this you need an *abstraction layer* built on top of mysqli, to do all the dirty job for you. Such a layer will actually let it in one line

```
if ($db->getOne("SELECT 1 FROM UserData WHERE Username=?s", $_POST['mx1'])) {
    echo "Username is already taken<br />";
}
```

There is also a funny logical error - you are starting with red span when not a single error found yet.

Comment: May I ask, do you use mysqli in your own projects? Or just as an exercise to answer questions on SO?

Comment: I take it you're asking me. I use anything that actually "works". Contributing to SQL injection, is NOT my cup of tea.

Comment: So, there is an existing project where you actually used the same code as you posted here?

Comment: Oh you mean the one that got downvoted? for no reason I might add.

Comment: Or are you not aware that using `*` for a SELECT isn't safe? You of all people should know this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using SELECT *. Just another superstition of PHP folks.

Comment: Sure, whatever you say. I'll stick with using columns.

Comment: We'll assume the OP knows what `getOne()` is.

Comment: He can easily find out. The problem is that for some reason most OPs care very little for the answers they get. Especially if their question is offtopic.

Comment: I should be `-1` your answer but you see, I'm not like that. I don't downvote answers, there's no point in doing so, not for me anyway. Your answer deserves a downvote because you failed to provide additional information on that function. Probably the reason the OP didn't accept your answer, which makes sense. Next time you give an answer, don't be lazy and provide the "why" and not the "why not".